# Links among html static website pages don't work when the pages are hosted on S3

Tags: html, amazon-s3

Probably it is a simple issue but I'm an html rookie and I have looked online without being able to find an answer.
I have developed an html static website starting from a free template online.
The structure works perfectly on local (file:///Users/...) but once hosted on AWS s3 I noticed that not all links to the html pages work.

The code is shown here below:

```html
    <div class="mainmenu-area">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                </div> 
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="Product1.html">Products</a></li>
                        <li><a href="Categories.html">Categories</a></li>
                        <li><a href="Contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>  
            </div>
        </div>
```

Namely, even though the Categories.html and Contact.html pages exist, when I click on those links I am linked back to the index page. On the opposite, links to the other two pages are fine.
Can someone let me know where should I look to fix this/what kind of mistake am I doing?

Thank you

Comment: This page will probably help. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/WebsiteHosting.html

Comment: @JS KIM. No, I don't think it's related to S3 in particular as the other links work. It should be something within the HTML/JS/CSS code but I can't find what it is